# Redirect all subfolders except one to root (without breaking css and images)?

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, web

I'm using the JavaScript History API to change URLs when a user opens a modal on my site. It works just fine, unless you refresh the page. Of course, the subdirectory doesn't exist, so it throws a 404.

I would like to redirect all folders besides my `assets` and `download` folders. I can't figure out the .htaccess for the life of me.

EDIT

This is the farthest I've gone with the regular expression:

```
(\/(?!assets|download).*)
```

This works only halfway, as it captures any subfolder after `/assets/` or `/download/`.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (\/(?!assets|download).*) index.html
```

Just for fullness, here's what the expression looks like when plugged into regexr.com with some test data:

[image]

Comment: Can you show at least something you have tried so we can work from there?

Comment: @DusanBajic Fair enough. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I exactly understood what you need, but let's try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(assets|download)/
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L,QSA]
```